# Get datatable's row data on button click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

i have a problem with [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/cr4VDR1AZih8WiNxmKg6?p=preview) project.

I'm trying to create a crud menu, when hitting the Edit button the row's data will be transferred to a bootstrap modal and from there user will be able to edit.

Problem  : right now when hitting the row - the modal opens perfectly with the row's data  - but when i try to change it to get the data by pressing on the button ('.edit_btn') ,it dos't works. i know that the button doesn't holds any data - so that's why it's probably don't work....

```
 $('#example tbody').on('click',  '.edit_btn', function () { // works only 
    when replacing 'tr' with  '.edit_btn' //
    var data_row = table.row(this).data(); // row's data

    $("#myModal").modal('show');

    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {

        $('#name').val(data_row.id);
        $('#type').val(data_row.type);
        $('#camp').html(data_row.campaign);

    });

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would use a delegated event handler `tbody .edit_btn` and grab the row through `closest('tr')` :

```
$('#example').on('click', 'tbody .edit_btn', function () {
    var data_row = table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
    ...
})
```

forked plunkr -> **https://plnkr.co/edit/58vkkp3M6d68uuMknXus?p=preview**

Comment: @RoyBarOn The delegation just to be sure it works on all pages (on a paginated table) and `closest()` to be sure the right `<tr>` is used for data-retrieval.

Comment: davidkonrad  - Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Got it...

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', '.edit_btn', function () {

     var data_row = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data(); // here is the change
    $("#myModal").modal('show');

    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {

       $('#name').val(data_row.id);
        $('#type').val(data_row.type);
        $('#camp').html(data_row.campaign);

    });

});
```

Comment: If you set DataTable to responsive and open in small device, this method will fail, because column will reduced in different parents.