# Clickable ID column and show the details of that row Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

i've tried make my id column (CMGUnmaskedID) is clickable, and show details of that row in new page or another div(that before is hidden).
i've tried this code

```
"processing" : true,
"serverSide" : true,
"columnDefs": [ {
  "targets": 0,
  "data": "CMGUnmaskedID",
  "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
    return '<a href="">'+data+'</a>';
  } 
}]
```

but i dont know how to get id (CMGUnmaskedID) for that row and pass that id to new page/div and call it in new page/div to show details.
im try this solutions but i didnt work for my case.
[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43435900/get-datatables-row-data-on-button-click)

Comment: Please add a working example of your table with full config and html.

Comment: `data` === `CMGUnmaskedID` ...